# Kendo UI TimePicker does raise change event on keyup event

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm, kendo-timepicker

I am a having a TimePicker and I would like to bind the keyup event.
The below code is not working.

```
<input id="tpActivationStartTime" data-value-update="keyup"
                                  data-role="timepicker"
                                  data-bind="value:activationStartDate, enabled: enableActivationStartDate" />

// javascript
viewModel.bind("change", function (e) {
    $("#btnApplySettings").attr("disabled", false);
});
```

The keyup event is never raised when I change the timePicker by editing the TimePicker textbox manually. It only works fine when I use the select button and pick a date. the change event is never raised on timepicker keyup event.

Comment: Could you give more details? What do you mean by "not working". Can you give the JavaScript code?

Comment: I am trying to call the change event on keyup event. the keyup event is never raised.

Comment: the change event is only called when you tab out of the timepicker; as long as you're typing in the correct format (which you can configure with parse-formats), it should work